# What's the strongest way to wake up monitors on linux?

Tags: power-management, multi-monitor, hdmi

I have a bad driver or something, but I see this is an old bug that has never been fixed.

Sometimes my monitor will be so firmly asleep after long period of inactivity - 10 hours or more  that only computer reboot will wake them up. It is always the one connected to hdmi which is 2560x1440, other DVI connected 1920x1200 works fine.

I am looking for slightly less strong way, but that works. Because this stuff is ineffective:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/12307/how-do-i-re-activate-wake-the-monitors-from-the-command-line

Also not sure where to report the bug (where it matters). I am on linux mint 18 but I see it's a problem on fedora 17 as well:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=747162